# Can Arab countries help Palestine to be free in the Palestine-Israel conflict?

Tags: israel, palestine

Do Arab countries have the ability to help Palestine to be free - as it was before 1948 - in its war against israel like US do with israel?

Comment: This question is very vague. First, what do you mean by “being free”? Becoming an independent state perhaps? Second, “helping” can be almost anything, small and large.

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: Downvotes! It's just a question :<(

Comment: @ZeyadEtman well, it's not a well-formulated one. I didn't downvote, but the question would benefit from being narrowed down - for example, you could propose some course of action and then ask why Arabic states do not act like that - this would be a better question. As your question is right now, the answer would be "Some of them (Quatar, for example) are already helping by financing Islamist groups in Gaza Strip".

Comment: Regarding your edit -  as others noted, before 1948 Palestine was a British-administrated entity, and I doubt your question was about restoring British rule. You should give a definition of what constitutes "free Palestine" in the scope of your question, as different groups in the region seem to have wildly different views on that subject.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Your question includes a premise, that there was a state named Palestine before 1948, and that it was free. Neither of these premises is true. Before 1948 the land where Israel resides was under a British mandate by the League of Nations. Before that it was under the Ottoman Empire rule for about 400 years. A series of regional and European powers ruled this country before that, back to the Greek Empire, but none of them was Palestine.

Considering the above, there is no Palestine Arab countries can help. But if we take this as "Can Arab countries start a war against Israel in order to establish Palestine in its stead?", then personally I don't see this happening, considering 1) how divided the Arab world is, and 2) the difference in military power between Israel and its neighbors.

Comment: Minus vote due to controversial and unsourced claims.

Comment: I wish I could upvote the first paragraph and downvote the second.

Comment: What claims, @liftarn?

Comment: @TsahiAsher The final paragraph. That is unsupported by sources and the claim is exceptional and as you know exceptional claims require exceptional sources.

Comment: The historical precedent is on @TsahiAsher's side. Neighbouring Arab countries *did* start wars with Israel, and they lost them all.

Comment: @Caleth Citation needed. Most of the wars was started by Israel. Although they may have been pre-emptive.

Comment: @liftarn [Wars involving Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_Israel). The point is not "who started it" but "who won". And it seems I was incorrect about "won them all", it is instead "won most"

Comment: @liftarn - the ur example (and probably the most important one here) is war of 1948. Which was very much certainly started by Arab states.

Comment: IMO "help Palestine to be free" does not directly translate to "start war with Israel"

Comment: @SharonBenAsher, considering how vague and baseless this question is, one can translate it however one wishes to.

Comment: @TsahiAsher, vague and baseless quesetions should be downvoted and/or closed, not translated according to personal wishes